# There is a wrapping bug for tag feed links

Tags: bug, formatting, hyperlinks

At the bottom of [this page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15), I see the following:

[image]

The blue words should really be "recently active technological-development feed", and the text should wrap. A similar effect shows up [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15) for [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science):

[image]

This wrapping is done properly elsewhere on Stack Exchange, e.g. on Physics (using [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15) as an example):

[image]

Can this be fixed?

As an alternate fix, I suggest moving the start of the feed link to the far left, as indicated by the big red arrow in the first image. No wrapping needed, thanks to the tag character limit.

I'm using Internet Explorer on Windows 7, if that helps. But I'm not sure why the wrapping would be fine on one site and not fine on another, if it's a browser issue.

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome and [worse in Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/99cSm.png).

Comment: I can get it on Astronomy, too (e.g. [here](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fundamental-astronomy?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15)). I'm not sure if this might be better on Meta.

Comment: I would have blamed it on IE, had other browser users not confirmed it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I would have, too, but seeing it work on Physics made me think twice.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing we can do about it here.